# FTP Upload using new thread and waiting for upload to finish

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ftp, delphi-xe

I can't seem to figured out what I'm doing wrong, I have the following code to upload a file to the ftp, its on a new thread, how can I tell it to wait for the upload to complete before proceeding?

```
procedure TFTPThread.Execute;
begin
  FTPClient.Host:=FTPAddress;
  FTPClient.Username:=FTPUsername;
  FTPClient.Password:=FTPPassword;
  FTPClient.Connect;
  FTPClient.Put(ZipFileName,'Logs.zip');
  FTPClient.Quit;
  FTPClient.Disconnect;
end;
```

I found this online, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

E2233 Property 'Handle' inaccessible here

```
  while WaitForSingleObject(TFTPThread.Handle, 0) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Comment: If you want to wait, why are you using a thread? You should use an event driven solution dealing with threads

Comment: You don't show where you hold a reference to the thread. If you have one you write Thread.WaitFor. As Sir Rufo says, why are you using threads and then synchronising. If you really want to process messages and wait do it properly with a non busy loop. That would be MsgWaitForMultipleObjects. But event driven is better. Handle OnTerminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdFTP.Put()` is a blocking method, it does not exit until the upload is finished.  So the thread itself is already waiting, by design.

Your compiler error is because you are trying to access the `Handle` property from the `TFTPThread` class type itself, but it is not declared as a `class` property so you cannot do that.  You need to access the `Handle` property through a pointer to a `TFTPThread` object instead:

```
FTPThread := TFTPThread.Create;
...
while WaitForSingleObject(FTPThread.Handle, 0) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

On the other hand, `TThread` has its own `WaitFor()` method, you don't need to call `WaitForSingleObject()` directly (unless you want to specify a non-infinite timeout, which `WaitFor()` does not support):

```
FTPThread := TFTPThread.Create;
...
FTPThread.WaitFor;
```

Comment: HI Remy, I'm not sure how to create the pointer to the TFTPThread, where would this go: FTPThread := TFTPThread.Create;

Comment: You wrote a thread class, how are YOU currently using it? Obviously, you can't `Execute` a thread that you do not `Create`.